# Skipping spaces in words of a given column while importing text file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, txt

I am trying to import a dataset from a text file, which looks like this.

```
id  book    author
1   Cricket World Cup: The Indian Challenge Ashis Ray
2   My Journey  Dr. A.P.J. Abdul Kalam
3   Making of New India Dr. Bibek Debroy
4   Whispers of Time    Dr. Krishna Saksena
```

When I used for importing:

```
df = pd.read_csv('book.txt', sep=' ')
```

it results into:

[image]

and when I use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('book.txt')
```

it results into:

[image]

Is there a way to get something like:

[image]

Any help on this will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the separator is not a tab?

Comment: Perhaps your file uses tabs to separate columns? Open your file in a text editor that shows whitespace characters to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with tab as a seperator:

```
df = pd.read_csv('book.txt', sep='\t')
```

Comment: happy to help!!

Comment: Thank you ! I have added an another question. Could you help me out there too?